# Compiler dependency and well defined output

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards, undefined-behavior

Is the output of this code well defined ?
I thought that it is updating the variable more than once between two successive sequence points.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int p=10,*q;
 q= &p;
 *q=p+++*q;
 printf("%d",*q);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 6.5p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
> a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
> computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
> undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
> unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings

Because `q` contains the address of `p`, the expression `*q=p+++*q;` is writing `p` twice (once with the postincrement operator directly on `p` and once when assigning to `*q`) without an intervening sequence point or other sequenced operations.  This violates the above clause disallowing more than one unsequenced side effect on an object.

Comment: thanks a lot. I thought the same too. Actually this was given in a numerical answer type question in one of the competitive exams for computer science and engineering. I was puzzled and confused at the exam hall, because I knew it will be undefined according to standards. So it was a wrong question. Thnx a lot again.

Comment: Even leaving the assignment out of it, the evaluation of `p+++*q` has undefined behavior all by itself, based on the same provision.  The side effect of `p++` (on the object designated by `p`) is unsequenced relative to the the value computation of `*q`, which uses the value of the same object.

Comment: @dbush Very sorry, I am new to stack overflow and didn't know that I can even accept an answer with that check. Thanks for guiding me. I found your answer really helpful.